# accordion header to align with content

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have written accordion in jquery. However, I want my accordion header to be aligned with the content with respect to screen size.

When the screen is small, it is centered.
[image]

But when the screen is big, it is not centered
[image]

```
table, th, td {
    border: 1px solid black;
    border-collapse: collapse;
    border-spacing: 20px;
}

th, td {
    padding: 15px;
    text-align: left;
    font-size:12px;
}
```

jfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/xg7cr0g4/48/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set `text-align:center` style to `<div id="accordion" ... >`